# Migrate Dotnet framework from 4.5.1 to Dotnet Core 2 frequent issues

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a plan to upgrade my dotnet application from Dotnet framework 4.5.1 to Dotnet Core 2, I would like to know what would be the issues in doing same? The reason for this migration is to support the application in LINUX servers as well

Comment: What did you try so far? At least [.NET Core vs .NET Framework: How to Pick a .NET Runtime for an Application](https://stackify.com/net-core-vs-net-framework/)?

Answer (score 2):

These 2 links helped me to perform the upgrade:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer

https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/314/upgrading-to-net-core-and-net-standard-made-easy